# How can i get all pictures name from folder using javascript and libraries such as angularjs and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I've got two sliders on my page, and i need to do a button, wich will upload new picture, that will be appearing in this sliders, the solution i found is, using AJAX or angularjs's $http.get method, receive this pictures names, and then use it in my functions, but not one option did not work, can i do this without some backend languages, using javaScript?

I tried something like this:

```js
$http.get('images').success(function(data) {
 $scope.images = data;
});
```

and this what i've got:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Index of /images</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<h1>Index of /images</h1>
<table><tr><th><img src="/icons/blank.gif" alt="[ICO]"></th><th><a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a></th><th><a href="?C=M;O=A">Last modified</a></th><th><a href="?C=S;O=A">Size</a></th><th><a href="?C=D;O=A">Description</a></th></tr><tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/back.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td><td><a href="/">Parent Directory</a>       </td><td>&nbsp;</td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/image2.gif" alt="[IMG]"></td><td><a href="photo_1.jpg">photo_1.jpg</a>            </td><td align="right">03-Jul-2015 14:21  </td><td align="right">396K</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/image2.gif" alt="[IMG]"></td><td><a href="photo_2.jpg">photo_2.jpg</a>            </td><td align="right">03-Jul-2015 14:22  </td><td align="right">392K</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/image2.gif" alt="[IMG]"></td><td><a href="photo_3.jpg">photo_3.jpg</a>            </td><td align="right">03-Jul-2015 14:21  </td><td align="right">475K</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/image2.gif" alt="[IMG]"></td><td><a href="photo_4.jpg">photo_4.jpg</a>            </td><td align="right">03-Jul-2015 14:21  </td><td align="right">173K</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/image2.gif" alt="[IMG]"></td><td><a href="photo_5.jpg">photo_5.jpg</a>            </td><td align="right">03-Jul-2015 14:29  </td><td align="right">396K</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/image2.gif" alt="[IMG]"></td><td><a href="photo_6.jpg">photo_6.jpg</a>            </td><td align="right">12-Jul-2015 21:45  </td><td align="right">211K</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/image2.gif" alt="[IMG]"></td><td><a href="photo_7.jpg">photo_7.jpg</a>            </td><td align="right">12-Jul-2015 21:45  </td><td align="right"> 97K</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/image2.gif" alt="[IMG]"></td><td><a href="photo_8.jpg">photo_8.jpg</a>            </td><td align="right">12-Jul-2015 21:45  </td><td align="right">570K</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/image2.gif" alt="[IMG]"></td><td><a href="photo_9.jpg">photo_9.jpg</a>            </td><td align="right">12-Jul-2015 21:45  </td><td align="right">124K</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr>
</table>
<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.3.13 Server at sliders.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Comment: You can't it's a security flaw, you need to use ajax with js and some server side language such as PHP.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I look for how can I do this using php and js

Comment: can't read directories on server using client side code

Comment: Yes, you will need to make sure that the php is outputting the images in the correct format the javascript `$scope.images` requires, this is unknown to me, however if you script is failing, check the response from the PHP file and make sure it's in a format your slider expects. Probably JSON.

Comment: Take a look at this article: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/